# How to remove tiny color type in this example

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am using Adobe Photoshop CS5, and I have this problem.

I have this original image, and what I want is to remove the red image and keep only the yellow plant image.

[image]

So, with my poor experience I went for the **Magic Wand Tool** and removed it and here is the result.

[image]

However if you see closely there are still red colored parts left specially in the corners of the plant.

One way to clear that seems to enlarge the image and use a **Pencil Tool** with white color and target the individual red places, but as I find myself working on similar images repeatedly, I find this solution cumbersome and sub-optimal.

Is there any good solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Zoom in on the red area
- **Menu Select** > **Color Range** > **Sampled Colors**... > get the dropper and click a red pixel > increase the Fuzziness > OK
- Delete
- If the yellow part is a layer, **Menu Layer** > **Matting** > **Defringe** = 1 px

[image: Laurel]

But the best way to do that is using the **Magic Wand Tool** and clicking the yellow area >

- Then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>J</kbd> (Mac) or
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>J</kbd> (Win) to create a
  layer via cut
- To this new layer, **Menu Layer** > **Matting** > **Defringe** = 1 px
- Delete the red background layer

Comment: Thanks. Can you add a simple text what this tells Adobe todo? I mean the about its purpose or function?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean

Comment: I mean, right now I can follow your instruction and get the job done but I will always assume the settings are to remove dots ... I just want to know the reason they are made for. "Matting > Defringe" .. what do we use them for?

Comment: Every time you copy/paste a selección, comes with the pixels at the edge from the "antialiasing". It is possible to delete them using  Defringe.